# bootstrap collapsible div disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using collapsible div option to my html table

```html
<table>
  <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@item.PendingRequest.TicketNumber" class="collapsed>
     <button onclick=" popupload(); "> </button>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <div class="collapse " id="@item.PendingRequest.TicketNumber ">
            data after collapse
     </div>
       
  </tr>
</table>
```

when i click table row (tr), content expand and show. its working well. when i click button to load popup, collapsible function working, before load popup. i need to stop collapsible option when button click. how i do it

Comment: What about showing us what you have so far on the js and not just the HTML? It will be really hard to help you with just this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rvuzk3c2/1/
check this..when i click pop up button, collapsible is working. i need to stop it

Comment: @marcogmonteiro can u understand the question ?? :)

Comment: I understand the question pretty well, but you need some javascript, if you have none, that tells me you haven't tried anything. Asking for people to code for you before you even tried to solve the problem is not the correct way to go about it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (based on your fiddle in comment):

Add click event on whole `.panel-info`. Add id to `<button id="Popup">`

Then listen if button is clicked:

```js
event.target.id==="Popup"
```

if it is stop events before it:

```js
event.stopPropagation();
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7qg6pun0/1/

```js
document.querySelector(".panel-info").onclick = function(event) {myFunction()};
    
function myFunction() {
    if (event.target.id==="Popup"){
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert("clicked button");
    }
}
```